# In Rails, how can I force update the client's js/css files?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, caching, static-files

When I use `javascript_include_tag` or `stylesheet_link_tag` to include files, they have a number at the end to make it easier to circumvent browser caching (update the file without changing the number, the browser still uses the cached version; change the number, the browser will download and use the updated file).

But where does this number come from?  When is it updated?  And how can I manually update it?

I'm still using Rails 2.3.9, but I guess answers for any version of Rails would be helpful since I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, in Rails 2, the number comes from the file's last modification date, and is added to the link as a query parameter.  In Rails 3, it comes from a hash of the file's contents, and is added to the filename itself.  The latter should be an improvement - see [this page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care) for more on the difference between the two.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Read http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html