# Caching and asset fingerprinting javascript and css files in Rails 3.0.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, assets

I am under the impression through reading docs online that rails(v3.0.5) automatically adds version numbers to javascript and css files included via javascript_include_tag and stylesheet_link_tag. Looking into the source code of my webpage, I don't see these version numbers. In my index.html.haml file under views/layouts, I have the following

!!!
  %html
   %head
     %title Test

```
 = stylesheet_link_tag '/rails/stylesheets/test.css'
 = javascript_include_tag '/rails/javascripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js'
```

is this disabled somehow?

Comment: As far I know rails fingerprints assets only when asset pipeline is enabled. You should consider upgrading your rails gem and then enable asset pipelining for this feature.

Comment: I see. Yea this particular post misled me, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021022/in-rails-how-can-i-force-update-the-clients-js-css-files?rq=1. I think it best to upgrade as well or use a third party gem. Thanks.